# CoLab Accessing Files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

It is great that I can run jupyter notebooks in CoLab, but I am going crazy saving and loading files. For example, I am writing an assignment for my course and I include figures in it using the  HTML tag. (I want to use HTML instead of markdown images so I can set the width.) So in a Text cell I have

```
<img src="CoLab04.png" width="250">
```

This works fine when I run the jupyter notebook on my laptop, but in CoLab, it can't find the image **even when the image is in the same CoLab folder as the `ipynb` file**. Err.

I have similar problems saving data files. On my laptop I can use the normal python functions `open`, `write`, `close`, etc. That code runs without complaint, but the files do not show up on Google Drive. Not in the CoLab folder or any other folder when I search all of my Google Drive. Err. I  read TFM and use

```
from google.colab import drive, files
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
fig.savefig("LED12.png") # saves a figure as a file
files.download("LED12.png")
```

This downloads a file to my laptop. Then I have to upload the file to a Google Drive folder so my students can see it.

Am I missing something? Why is it so hard to create and read Google Drive files using a Google-CoLab jupyter notebook?

I've read https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb, but why is it so hard? I need something easy for **novice** students to use. If reading and writing files is this hard, I will have to recommend my students install jupyter on their laptops and not use CoLab.

Comment: I had the same problem with saving file to drive from colab, I discovered that you can save only `txt` files directly to mounted drive. So I am using PyDrive to load my files directly from colab to drive.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me a `sys.path` problem.

After you mount `My Drive` by the following code

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

then your main Google Drive can be read with

```
!ls /content/drive/My Drive/
```

If you have a sub-folder under `My Drive` that you wish to centralize your colab project, let's say you have `projectA` folder under your main Google Drive directory. You can add the projectA folder path to `sys.path`

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/content/drive/My Drive/projectA")
```

Then you should be able to save your fig as the same way you used in your local machine root path. The file will be save to your `projectA` folder where you run your colab code.

```
fig.savefig("LED12.png")
```

You should be able to see the file appear there. If this doesn't work, then try using absolute path when doing `open`, `save`, `close` etc. path sensitive operation:

```
working_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/projectA'
fig.savefig(os.path.join(working_path, "LED12.png"))
```

Comment: thanks.  do i need to do this every time i need to save a file?

Comment: Yes, for every session, you need to mount My Drive again.

Answer (score 2):

It may be simpler to load notebooks from GitHub, wherein image links in the same repository will be loaded more intuitively.

For example, the notebook below loads a set of images bundled in its GitHub repository.

https://colab.research.google.com/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/05.01-What-Is-Machine-Learning.ipynb

The markdown reference for the first graph:

```
![](figures/05.01-classification-1.png)
[figure source in Appendix](06.00-Figure-Code.ipynb#Classification-Example-Figure-1)
```

This corresponds to the GitHub repo here:
  https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/

Building on this example, a common pattern for bundling data files is to add a `!git clone ...` command at the top of the notebook to bring in the entire repo in one shot.

The reason this is simpler to accomplish in GitHub than Drive is that GitHub has unified ACLs at a repostiory level, whereas Drive manages ACLs at the file level. So, it would be a bit cumbersome to have a Drive notebook shared publicly that referenced images or other Drive files that were not shared.

Comment: This just confirms that it will not be easy for a *novice* student.

Comment: @profhuster did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issues. I've also looked at kaggle which is only slightly less complicated but still more difficult then I would want my students to deal with.

Comment: No. I have students install python and run on their own laptops.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in Colab (reading, training my model and uploading my trained model) some days ago. Let's make it simple.
Please do the following steps. I am trying to cover both(reading csv as well as uploading a file).

**Step 1 :** Go to your google drive and create a folder: **Colab** and keep your files inside Colab folder.

**Step 2 :** Now, install pydrive in Colab jupyter notebook

```
!pip install pydrive
```

**Step 3 :** Run following commands for accessing Google drive File

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
```

**Step 4 :** Mount drive(Here you will get a link in Colab jupyter shell. Click the generated link and verify your google drive(Just copy and paste the generated code) )

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

**Step 5 :** Authenticate and create the PyDrive client. Here do the same like step 4 (Click the generated link and verify your google drive(Just copy and paste the generated code) )

```
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

**Step 6 :** To get the file, replace the id with id(your file id) of file you want to access. For me, it was csv file. To get the id, go to share and generate a link. you will find something like : https://drive.google.com/file/d/**xxxxxxxxxxxxxx**/view?usp=sharing. Put it(xxxxxxxxxxxxxx) on below and do the same, how many files you want to read.

```
normal_1 = drive.CreateFile({'id':'13AR0sS1pndF0fTxmdjQRv_1Bv5aBNpkT'}) 
normal_1.GetContentFile('normal_1.csv')

normal_2 = drive.CreateFile({'id':'1Z0DO8M1Qco07kyVoxYSgxXBx6XYGBzJd'}) 
normal_2.GetContentFile('normal_2.csv')

abnormal = drive.CreateFile({'id':'12zFHDXVjreorRrHHhYrA1n82VQLuawsl'}) 
abnormal.GetContentFile('abnormal.csv')
```

**Step 7 :** Now, you can read those files and load in a dataframe for further use.

```
normal_1 = pd.read_csv('normal_1.csv', skiprows = np.arange(100, normal_1.shape[0])) 
normal_2 = pd.read_csv('normal_2.csv', skiprows = np.arange(100, normal_2.shape[0])) 
abnormal = pd.read_csv('abnormal.csv', skiprows = np.arange(50, abnormal.shape[0]))
```

**Step 8 :** Save the model to disk after training your model:Use  joblib

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
filename = 'model.sav'
joblib.dump(clf, filename)

# Upload model to you google drive
model_file = drive.CreateFile({'title' : 'model.sav'})
model_file.SetContentFile('model.sav')
model_file.Upload()
```

Now, go to your My drive and refresh it. You will finding something "model.sav". For the complete code in jupyter notebook file, you can visit my [github](https://github.com/humaun21/Acees_Google_Drive_From_Colab/blob/master/Access_Google_Drive_File_From_Colab.ipynb) link. I hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: This answer makes the problem seem even worse. I want some thing easy for students beginning to program in python/jupyter notebooks.