# How to center-align a plot in a Jupyter cell

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I have the following plot in Jupyter Notebook, which by default is aligned to the left:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1.320, 1.127, 0.997, 0.800, 0.587, 0.441, 0.323])
y = np.array([0.4064, 0.2886, 0.2347, 0.1516, 0.0854, 0.0485, 0.0375]

lx = np.log (x)
ly= np.log (y)


z = np.polyfit(lx, ly, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(lx, p(lx), 'r-.')

plt.xlim(-1.25, 0.4)
plt.ylim(-4, -0.5)


plt.plot(lx, ly, '.')
plt.title('The effect of length on the period')
plt.xlabel('Length (L) / lg(m)')
plt.ylabel('Period (T) / lg(s)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(['Trend line', 'Experimental data'])
plt.show()

print(f"The equation of the curve is {p}")
```

I would like to all of this display as center-aligned, similar to what “< center >” does to text.

I have tried running the following code in the code-cell above:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("""
<style>
.output_png {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
""")
```

But as other people also have been experiencing when this question have been asked previously (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66492978/how-to-center-matplotlib-outputs-in-jupyter-notebooks) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380168/center-output-plots-in-the-notebook) question), this doesn’t work for me. It seems to work for only some people, despite what version they’re using. I have tried running it both before and after I have run the plot code, but nothing happens. I have read every available question asked about this on stack (as well as other sources) and am yet to find an answer. Does anyone have any other ideas on how I might be able to accomplish this?

I’m running Jupyter through Google Colab.

Comment: please explain this sentance: _"I would like to all of this display as center-aligned, similar to what does to text."_ or show what you mean with an example.

Comment: Please update your post and possibly title to: (1) document sources of this also "But as other people also have been experiencing when this question have been asked previously, this doesn’t work for me." (2) And then given what you can document from the first point, why this merits a post separate from any of that? (Hint: there's a lot of ways to run a Jupyter Notebook and you don't specify your version or flavor of Jupyter? Have things changed with Jupyter Notebook 7+ and the advice is for older versions and NbClassic?)

Comment: @D.L seems like the syntax I was referring to exists here as well, so it disappeared without me realizing haha. Hopefully it has been fixed now :)

Comment: @Wayne Thanks for the feedback, I have now corrected according to your suggestions.

Comment: 1. save the figure `plt.savefig('test.png')` 2. close the image without displaying it `plt.clf()` 3. As shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65989723/7758804), display the figure in a markdown cell with `<center><img src="test.png"/></center>`. [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya08W.png)

Comment: Since you're using colab, you may also need [CoLab Accessing Files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53653429/7758804)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney seems like a really great way to do it, but I can’t for the life of me get it to work. When I try what you mentioned, I get the icon for image not found/uploaded. But if I instead try IPython.display.image it has no problem retrieving the image. Same for imread in matplotlib. Why the difference?? I could’ve use the IPython way, had it not been for the fact that you can’t set the embed-parameter to False (which centers the image) in QTconsole.

Comment: "I’m running Jupyter through Google Colab." Just to follow-up, this sort of thing was why I was recommending more information in your post. Google Colab is a very highly modified version of Jupyter that, at this time, uses a very old version of the Jupyter software.